# Make icon appear after input

Tags: css, input

i have this search bar in my application which i want to modify:

[image]

Right now the "X"-Icon is visible from the beginning even tho it does nothing before an input was done, so i want to make it appear AFTER the user starts entering text.

The icon is a SVG i added and styled seperatly.

I don't realy know how i can do this, i thought its easy and i can just use something like "::after" but it seems that this it not possible with input fields.

Ps.: im an absolute beginner in CSS so please have mercy.

Comment: What is your code so far? Do you use any layout framework?

Comment: @ino im not realy sure how to answer this question, its a application, im just in charge to modfiy the styling and usability. The developers used react for most stuff and also some Material UI compenents (which i am trying to "kill" right now).

Comment: Set `display:none;` in JS when text is entered set the CSS property for `display` to something else like `block`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible with CSS. You would have to use Javascript.

Javascript

```
// set the id of the x button to x-button
// set the id of the input field to input
var x_button = document.getElementById("x-button");
var input = document.getElementById("search-input");
input.oninput = function(){
if(this.value) x_button.classList.add("visible");
else x_button.classList.remove("visible");
}
```

CSS

```
.x-button { display:none;}
.visible {display:block;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way to achieve your requirement would be to have different `classes` which `shows/hides` the icon by checking when `input` is not empty in `JS`.

If you want to achieve without using JS you can target the adjacent `button` element when the `input` is focussed and add `::before` pseudo element and style it.

```
input:focus+button:before {
    content: "X";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it is possible if you wanna do it using only css.

```css
#Search{
font-size:22px;
color:green;
background-image:url('images/search.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;outline:0;
}

#Search::-webkit-search-cancel-button{
    position:relative;
    right:20px;    
}
```

```html
<input id="Search" name="Search" type="search" placeholder="Search" />
```